# React router, weird behaviour, doubled path

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I found a weird behavior of react-router, it duplicates added path in the address line.
[my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jlmy79v9vy)

When we click on a course once the url changes properly, when we click on any other (or the same) course the added path doubles, so on the third click it reverses back to normal path.

Example: the path in the address line becomes :

```
first click: /courses/course/1

second: /courses/course/:id/course/1

third: /courses/course/1
```

Where the problem comes from?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by changing your `push()` within `Courses.js` to be a path relative to the root to match your `Route` definition. Note the forward flash `/` at the beginning and the removal of `${path}`:

```
this.props.history.push(`/courses/course/${course.id}`, {
  title: course.title
});
```

Here is a working forked [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7m4wzv968q) that includes a few different approaches to this issue.

Another approach would be to use [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) or [NavLink](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) instead of an `<article>` with `onClick` and having to `push()` to `history`. You can still pass state property `title` as you are currently doing using `Link` or `NavLink`. This is exactly what `Link` and `Navlink` were meant to be used for:

```
{this.state.courses.map(course =>
  <Link
    key={course.id}
    to={{
      pathname: `/courses/course/${course.id}`,
      state: { title: course.title }
    }}
  >
    {course.title}
  </Link>
)
```

This would make the element an actual `<a>` the pattern would also open the door to using something like [NavLink](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) which could expose "active" style class for styling if necessary.

You may also consider simplifying the `Route` and `Link` to match more standard conventions:

```
<Route path="/courses/:id" exact component={Courses} />

// ...

<Link
  className="Course"
  key={course.id}
  to={{
    pathname: `/courses/${course.id}`,
    state: { title: course.title }
  }}
>
    {course.title}
</Link>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: path != pathname, Moreover early i was confused with _Match_ and _Location_ objects in _Router Props_ and applied `<Link to={{path: '/..' ...}}` instead of `<Link to={{pathname: '/..' ...}}` which caused me the problems with route and history. Thanks for your clarifications with multiple examples!